Carla No module named 'carla.libcarla'
Ive been trying to do some stuff with carla. When I tried opening generate_traffic.py in a cmd to create some traffic i get an error: No module named 'carla.libcarla'. I already looked through all other posts and downgraded to python 3.7 but seems to work.
here the failcode:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\carla\WindowsNoEditor\PythonAPI\examples\generate_traffic.py", line 24, in <module>
    import carla
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\carla\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .libcarla import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'carla.libcarla'

I just can't find any solution to this

try import carla.libcarla

sadly doesnt change anything

works on my system. Is there a path location issue?
